# Jhipster Azure AD Access token

Tags: reactjs, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, jhipster

I am using Azure AD access token instead of default openID connect server (keycloak) to protect the backend REST API. Could you please let me know if i need to make any changes for AuidenceValidator class under package security.oauth2.

**Application flow:**

UI(React JS) will access the Spring boot API by passing access token.

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: From UI using MSAL library acquiring azure access token and sending it to backend API call.let me know what changes i have to make to validate the jwt token send from UI.

I have wrote API's using Jhipster with spring Webflux. Like configuration changes for odic in application. Properties file and any changes on AudienceValidator class.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [ms-identity-java-webapi sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi). The `msal-obo-sample` shows how to validate an access token acquired by MSAL using Spring Security. You will be interested specifically in `AADClaimsVerifier` and `SecurityResourceServerConfig`